# How to re-render PayPal Smart Buttons with different values?

Tags: javascript, paypal

I'm using PayPal Smart button on my web site, and after each payment is made the user is able to make another new payment with PayPal smart button. The problem is that once I've created my PayPal button **I'm unable to set the new createOrder** in it with new orderID.

So in my website I have the following function which init the PayPal button if there is yet a pending order or it's called when a new order is made and I get a new orderID.

```
function initPayPal(orderID, publicKey) {
    var paymentID = $("#paypal-button-container").data("payment-id")
    var PAYPAL_SCRIPT =
        "https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=" + publicKey + "&currency=EUR&intent=capture&commit=false&vault=true";
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("src", PAYPAL_SCRIPT);
    script.onload = function () {
        paypal
            .Buttons({
                style: {
                    shape: "rect",
                    color: "gold",
                    layout: "horizontal",
                    label: "paypal",
                    tagline: false,
                    height: 52,
                },
                createOrder: async function () {
                    $(".body-payments").hide();
                    $(".loader-payments").show();
                    const res = await fetch(
                        "/api/payment/paypal/" + paymentID + "/" + orderID,
                        {
                            method: "post",
                            headers: {
                                "content-type": "application/json",
                            },
                            credentials: "include",
                        }
                    );
                    const data = await res.json();
                    return data.id;
                },
                onApprove: async function (data) {
                    const res = await fetch(
                        "/api/payment/paypal/capture/" + paymentID + "/" + data.orderID,
                        {
                            method: "post",
                            headers: {
                                "content-type": "application/json",
                            },
                            credentials: "include",
                        }
                    );
                    if (localStorage.STBOrder) {
                        localStorage.removeItem("STBOrder");
                    }

                    $("#modalPayments").modal("hide");
                    $("#modalSuccess").modal("show");
                    $(".body-payments").show();
                    $(".loader-payments").hide();

                },
                onCancel: function (data) {
                    $(".body-payments").show();
                    $(".loader-payments").hide();
                },
            })
            .render("#paypal-button-container");
    };
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Client id is set dynamically as each user on its own page will get the payment on its own account.  The issue here is that the button is initiated the first time all works fine, but if I dismiss the order and I call this function again it will create another button instead of setting new values to existing (already rendered) one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no need to init the button more than once.

Initialize the button one time (on page load).

Then, inside createOrder, ensure paymentID and orderID reference non-local variables or are replaced with function calls that will return the correct value at the time you want them to, e.g. some kind of getOrderID() of yours, and `$("#paypal-button-container").data("payment-id")` , in place of your existing local variables

---

In the unlikely event that you really did need to render the buttons more than once, you could save a reference to `myButtons = paypal.Buttons({..})` before calling .render() --- and then, later myButtons.close() before saving a new reference to and rendering a new buttons object. But again, there should be no reason to do that here.

Comment: Hi Preston, actually i've solved by doing `empty()` on paypal container so in this way when i'm recreating the `paypal.Button` it's not created multiple times, could this be one of the approaches or should i go for cuntion to get the orderID as you mentioned?

Comment: You should go for a function (or a global) and only init the button once. Recreating the button is not necessary and not recommended, but if you ever do need to do that the clean way is savig a reference and `.close() `

Comment: Ended up with a function passed as orderID